# How to measure confidence intervals for a time-based process

Tags: confidence-interval

How to measure confidence intervals for time-based process

I have a process for which I'm measuring a key variable (X), which is the error of the process, every 4 seconds. The value of X(t) at a particular time t is impacted to some extent by random variables, but it's also a function of the state of the system at time t-4 (the controller of the system is trying to mitigate error observed at time t-4, while various aspects of the system keep introducing new sources of error).

I have samples of X for every 4 seconds for 12 days. The 12 days are in different months and basically independent each other (unlike the samples of X that are relatively close in time) and relatively normally distributed.

From this I can compute the expected value of the mean of X over a year. I'm trying to estimate the 95% and 99% confidence intervals for that annual mean.

Can I just dump the large number of 4-second samples into the standard confidence interval formula given that they are not independent of each other? Or, do I have to use independent samples, which would limit me to the 12 daily samples? Or, is there some formula that lets me use non-independent samples correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x_{sd}$ be your observation at second $s$ of day $d$.

Here's my quick reaction on possible approaches:

#### Simplest approach

Define $y_d = \frac{1}{n_{d}} \sum_s x_{sd}$ were $n_d$ is the number of seconds on day $d$ Now each $y_d$ are basically independent.

Then compute your annual estimate $\bar{y} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_d y_d$ and compute your standard-errors etc.. the usual way. This is a highly intuitive approach. (In Finance, this is what [Fama and Macbeth](http://www.haas.berkeley.edu/groups/finance/standarderror.pdf) did back in the 1970s to get consistent standard-errors in the presence of cross-sectional correlation.)

#### Cluster approach

Run the regression:

$$ x_{sd} = \beta + \epsilon_{sd}$$

and cluster by day. For large number of days, you should get basically the same result as the simplest approach above. 12 days isn't very many though

#### Newey-West or Hansen-Hodrick approach:

The basic idea is that you allow error term $\epsilon_t$ to be correlated with $\epsilon_{t-1}, \ldots, \epsilon_{t-k}$ (i.e. correlated up to $k$ lags). Newey-West has the correlation fall off with distance.

Eg. if model is $x_t = \beta + \epsilon_t$ and you allow $k$ lags of correlation

\begin{align*} \mathrm{Var} \left( \frac{1}{T} \sum_t x_t \right) 
&= \frac{1}{T} \left(\mathrm{Var}\left(\epsilon_t\right) + 2\sum_{j=1}^k \mathrm{Cov}\left(\epsilon_{t}, \epsilon_{t+j} \right) \right) 
\end{align*}

And so you estimate with something like: $\hat{\mathrm{Var}}\left(\epsilon_t\right) = \frac{1}{n-1} e_t^2$ and $\hat{\mathrm{Cov}}\left(\epsilon_t, \epsilon_{t-j}\right) = \frac{1}{n-j} e_te_{t-j}$

#### Add even more structure, estimate a AR model or a VAR

A classic auto-regression model is something like:

$y_t = a + b y_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$

The idea is that if you condition on lagged values of your series, the $\epsilon_t$ are independent. You can check the sample autocorrelation function of the residuals to see if accounting for lagged terms makes the residuals uncorrelated.